# C# identifier "System" is undefined

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# using C# through visual studios and downloaded through Enterprise. I'm trying to begin with the hello world project. However, the program will not compile because for some reason it won't recognize the "System" identifier.
Here is my code (which i copied straight from a tutorial)...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using different #includes and removing the usings and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks good to me....

Comment: What do you see in the "References" section in the Solution Explorer tree for this project?

Comment: Did you create a C++ project?

Comment: That sounds like a C/C++ error and you are using the term #includes when explaining the issue. Are you sure you are not attempting to compile C# code with a C/C++ compiler?

Comment: I can see that it's a console application but what framework of .net are you pointing at?  What year (2012, 2013, 2015, 2017) and version (Pro, Enterprise etc) of Visual Studio are you using?   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx). Lastly can you link to the tutorial you are referencing?

Comment: She used the C++ project template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the C++ project template,

- Close Visual Studio
- Open Visual Studio
- Click New Project
- Choose Visual C#
- Choose Console Application
- Type a project name or leave the default one
- Click OK

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much and pardon my stupid mistakes :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are seeing System in the list of References under your solution in the Solution Explorer window.

1. If you do not see it there then you need to add it by using NuGet Package manager (found under the tools menu in Visual Studio).
2. If do find System in the list of References under your solution in the Solution Explorer window try creating a new project or rebuilding the solution after cleaning it (found under the Build menu in Visual Studio).

Both of these have worked for me in the past. Good Luck I hope this helps
I copied her code into a C# console application project and ran it and it worked just fine. She is using a C# code template

Her Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Code taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/hello-world-your-first-program

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The only major difference is the lack of string[] args in Main() which is not needed as it is optional

Here is the program copied exactly from her code using Visual Studio and a C# console application project running:
[Picture of Program code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SPqA.png)